# Restrict custom fields based on user roles

Tags: user-roles, advanced-custom-fields

I have search far and wide for this and the only solution i can find it restricting the amount of posts users can make.

We have a WP site that we would like to monetize with a simple directory of sorts for a very niche market. We would like to have various levels of advertising partners that have access to certain fields dependent on their level.

Example Gold would have 10 images, Bronze might have 1. Or gold has the "website" field.

I am using ACF heavily over the site, and i do not need payment plugins or a front-end solution, we can work out the payment side separately and we will be using the Wordpress backend. I just need to be able to modify field availability based on a users role. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a plugin called "ACF User Role Field Setting" that restricts the fields available based on users role. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution: create a custom post type for each level, and use CPT permissions so you can assign them rights to only edit their level of CPT and never see the others. You can then assign a different ACF fieldset for each post type.

Use the same names for fields within the fieldsets, and then when you grab the data it will all be formatted the same way, you'll just check `if(get_field('field_name')) {` and do nothing if that field doesn't exist for that post. Or, you can create a `single-{cpt}.php` for each post type and control the front end layout that way.

Comment: I thought about that as a potential solution. My thoughts where that i would not be able to create an archive view if they where in different post types?

Comment: Instead of a traditional archive you'd create an archive yourself. I'd set up a Page with a custom page template, and within that custom template, you can run a `WP_Query` that pulls all of your CPTs together.

Comment: That may just work. Benefits of that is layouts for individual advertising levels could easily be done. Ill try this and come back with a report of how it goes.